# Erase results from terminal without erasing command history

Tags: macos, terminal, history

Is there a way (MAC OSX) to keep all the commands you entered in the terminal history but clear all the results of those commands from the visual display?

Comment: That is the default behavior.

Comment: What is? - the behaviour I'm asking for (keep command history but erase outputs) or the behaviour I want to over-ride (keep both or erase both (by restarting terminal))?

Comment: Default behaviour is for `history` to only contain the commands you enter, not any output.

Comment: ok, I suppose I meant "the visual display" then and will edit the question to reflect this. But who votes to close a question about the terminal for being off topic?

Comment: Question belongs on http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com, since it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 2):

The keystroke ctrl-L or the command `clear` will clear the screen. Your Bash history is not affected at all.

Comment: Although those only clear the terminal screen. They don't clear the scrollback, if that's what @wheresrhys is asking. For that, use View > Clear Scrollback (Command-K).